# Using PXFormula with Selector on a DAC with multiple key fields

Tags: acumatica

I have two custom fields that I've added, `SOShipment.usrActualFreightCost`, and `SOFreightDetail.usrWMSFreightCost`. I would like UsrWMSFreightCost field on SOFreightDetail to be populated with the data in UsrActualFreightCost on SOShipment.

It seemed to me the simplest way to do this would be to use PXFormula with Selector like so.

```
public class SOFreightDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOFreightDetail>
{
  #region UsrWMSFreightCost
  [PXDBDecimal]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName="WMS Freight Cost")]
  [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOFreightDetail.shipmentNbr, SOShipmentExt.usrActualFreightCost>))]
  public virtual Decimal? UsrWMSFreightCost { get; set; }
  public abstract class usrWMSFreightCost : IBqlField { }
  #endregion
}
```

However, the SOShipment DAC has 2 key fields, `ShipmentNbr` and `ShipmentType`, so I don't know how to correctly use Selector to retrieve the shipment.

Is it possible to use the Selector with multiple key fields or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: You could add a unique ID field (non-key) to SOFreightDetail and make the selector operate on that key. Details on how to do that can be found in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174705/how-to-make-sure-specific-line-from-pxselector-is-chosen/48190736#48190736

Answer (score 0):

The first generic parameter of `Selector<,>` formula must be a field with `PXSelectorAttribute`.
Your particular implementation will not work because `SOFreightDetail.shipmentNbr` field does not have `PXSelectorAttribute`.
You can try to customize this field by `PXVirtualSelectorAttribute` but the selector must obtain the shipment type itself, for example:

```
[PXVirtualSelector(
    typeof(Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, 
        Where<SOShipment.shipmentType, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentType>>>>))]
```

This implementation will work only if the current record of the shipment cache is not null, e.g. `SOShipment` is primary entity of the graph.
Also formulas may not support the cache extensions. It depends on the version of Acumatica you are using.

Try the proposed solution and write me about result in comments.